# How to Create Sourcemaps with GruntJs Terser JS Minify

Tags: gruntjs

I'm using Terser for Gruntjs to minify js files.
I want to be able to create a sourcemap but I don't know how to translate the samples I see in the options section (https://www.npmjs.com/package/terser#source-map-options) into my gruntfile.js.

Here is the section where I am minifying and I added where I think the sourceMap options go:

```js
grunt.initConfig({

    terser: {
        pages: {
            options: {
                mangle: {
                    properties: false
                },
                sourceMap: {
                    // source map options goes here I think but not certain what
                }
            },
            files: [
                {   expand: true, 
                    src: '**/*.js', 
                    dest: 'wwwroot/js', 
                    cwd: 'wwwroot/js',
                    ext: '.min.js'
                }
            ]
        }
    }
});
```

**I cannot find a gruntjs example for this anywhere so any input or help would be great**

Comment: I figured it out by looking at a webpack plugin example - code updated in answer below

Comment: On line [#59](https://github.com/adascal/grunt-terser/blob/master/tasks/terser.js#LC59) of the `grunt-terser` source code it shows that `filename` for  `sourceMap` would be a valid property/key, however if you excluded it it would default to naming the source-map file the same as the resultant minified `.js` file plus a `.map` suffix. I haven't tried grunt-terser however I  would try something like these [examples](https://paste.ee/p/FxvXX). Given that your `files` config is going to generate multiple files I'd probably try _Example 2_ first.

Comment: @RobC Thanks!  Exactly what I was looking for - I was getting ready to move on to other project and needed to tie off this issue - good job!

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer and have tested it.  Note the `sourceMap` entry in the `options` below:

```js
grunt.initConfig({

    terser: {
        pages: {
            options: {
                mangle: {
                    properties: false
                },
                sourceMap: true
            },
            files: [
                {   expand: true, 
                    src: '**/*.js', 
                    dest: 'wwwroot/js', 
                    cwd: 'wwwroot/js',
                    ext: '.min.js'
                }
            ]
        }
    }
});
```